# puma-dev creates another socket and ignores rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, puma-dev

I'm trying to setup `puma-dev` for some subdomains locally, I'm on ubuntu so I've followed the steps on github to have it run in the foreground, created a symlink on `~/.puma-dev` to my rails app.

What's happening is when I try to access my subdomain, a new instance of Puma is started in a new socket, this ignore my rails server that is already running. This means that I don't receive the logs on my rails server tab, so it gets pretty hard to debugg code. Not sure how to make the `puma-dev` use the rails server that I started.

Heres the processes, you can see we have 2 puma instances, the one on tcp:localhost:3000, and the one in puma-dev-sock-984.sock.

Is there way to have only the rails server instance?
[image]

additional info:
`sudo netstat -tlnp`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40073         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21077/ruby /home/mm 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7599/redis-server * 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57621           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20408/spotify       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      846/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54807           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20408/spotify       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      882/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29730/puma 4.3.5 (t 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1090/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      7599/redis-server * 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1128/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      984/puma-dev        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      882/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3000                :::*                    LISTEN      29730/puma 4.3.5 (t 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      984/puma-dev
```